# PHP and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect to MongoDB via PHP.

```
mongod --version
db version v3.2.8
```

Then,

```
php -i | grep mongo
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini,
 mongodb
 mongodb support => enabled
 mongodb version => 1.1.8
 mongodb stability => stable
 libmongoc version => 1.3.5
 mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

I tried:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

which returns

```
pecl/mongodb is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.8 
install failed
```

which (the install failed bit) gets redressed if I try:

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongodb
```

and

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

I have this php file:

```
<?php

echo "I am here";
$connection = new Mongo('localhost');
$db = $connection->mydb;

$list = $db->listCollections();
foreach ($list as $collection) {
    echo "$collection </br>";       
}

echo "I am never here";
?>
```

I cannot see the second echo.

I would appreciate any thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: First echo phpinfo(); and see mongo extension is there or not? If not there then mongo is not installed successfully.

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356834/mongodb-connect-using-php

Comment: @SanjayChaudhari Thank you very much! Indeed there is. There is a mongodb section with the info from php -i.

Comment: @KarthiVenture Thank you! I saw that post earlier. Tried everything there but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check @sanjay comment and then apply this connection:

```
$db = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost', [
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'db'       => 'YOUR DB'
]);
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you! I tried but I only see the first echo. When I login to Mongo shell from the command line I don't use any username/password. So, for username and password I just put '' (blank).

Comment: I am wondering, could it be a problem that mongod is 3.2.8 whereas mongodb version (from php -i) is 1.1.8?

Comment: Which version you used ?

Comment: sorry for sounding a little bland, but I cannot be sure of that. Further, when I login to mongo shell I get this message: "Connecting  to: test" which I dismiss :) I am quite confused.

Comment: Kindly check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16769216/3081659. It's related to your current problem.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! Appreciate it! To be honest, I have seen that post as I have been trying all day today to 'connect' mongodb with php. Checked quite a variety of things before posting here. The problem is that my hopes are fading and am not sure how to start over.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have it working. Thanks to this post:
[After upgrading PHP to version 7, why can't I use the mongodb driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604088/after-upgrading-php-to-version-7-why-cant-i-use-the-mongodb-driver)

and this post:
[Using the PHP Library for MongoDB (PHPLIB)](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php)

Sorry as it seems pretty odd (to me!) but indeed: MongoClient() has become (verbatim! with the slash!) MongoDB\Client().

Hence, the file I had in my original post becomes:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
echo "I am here";

$manager = new MongoDB\Client();

$database = $manager->mydb;


foreach ($database->listCollections() as $databaseInfo) {
    var_dump($databaseInfo);
}
echo "I managed to arrive here";
?>
```

and I can see the contents of mydb as well as the 2 echos. The vendor/autoload.php was generated by

```
sudo composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"
```

as I ran it from within the directory of the php file above. Probably not the best idea as I, now, have to resolve how to make the autoload.php (and all it carries with) globally available. But, nonetheless, at least, I managed to arrive somewhere.

I am using: PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (cli) ( NTS )
under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS